# How to position the camera to look at an object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a scene with a THREE.Object3D object in it.  The object consists of several child objects, so it does not have geometry directly.

How can I position and focus the camera to look at the object?

Answer (score 3):

```
camera.position.copy( object.position );
camera.position.z += object.geometry.boundingSphere.radius;
camera.lookAt( object );
```

Comment: I'm sorry for being a bit unclear.  But my object does not have a geometry, it is an object that has several child objects.